# Unexpected block head

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, pug

```
extends base
include _reviewCard

block append head
  script(src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.9.1/mapbox-gl.js')
  link(href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.9.1/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet')

mixin overviewBox(label, text, icon)
  .overview-box__detail
    svg.overview-box__icon
      use(xlink:href=`/img/icons.svg#icon-${icon}`)
    span.overview-box__label= label
    span.overview-box__text= text

block content
```

this gives me
`{"status":"error","error":{"code":"PUG:UNEXPECTED_BLOCK","msg":"Unexpected block head","line":4,"column":`...`

when i remove the block append head the code is rendering but the scripts are not loading

I followed a node tutorial and this block was added to add a script that shows map in my webpage

Comment: are you sure what the `base.pug` contains the `block head`?

Comment: Oh god, I guess my IQ really falls between binary range :). It's working block head was missing from base but i was looking for my error in another pug file. Thanks man